# Can't return last inserted row from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am trying to get the last inserted id from the stored procedure but I can't .

All I want is to get the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertProduct]
    @ProductName varchar(30),
    @ProductPrice decimal ,
    @ProductQuantity int,
    @id int output
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Product (ProductName, ProductPrice, ProductQuantity) 
    VALUES (@ProductName, @ProductPrice, @ProductQuantity)

    SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    RETURN  @id
END
```

and here is my C# code

```
var ProductParameters = new[] {
    new SqlParameter("@ProductName", Product.ProductName),
    new SqlParameter ("@ProductPrice", Product.ProductPrice),
    new SqlParameter ("@ProductQuantity", Product.ProductQuantity)
};

var y = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC sp_InsertProduct @ProductName, @ProductPrice, @ProductQuantity", ProductParameters);
```

Comment: @id should not be an OUTPUT parameter: simply return the value. I would suspect the SQL command call throws an error: pay attention any such "what didn't work" results.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just return the value from your stored procedure (no need to have an input parameter):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertProduct]
    @ProductName varchar(30),
    @ProductPrice decimal ,
    @ProductQuantity int
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Product (ProductName,ProductPrice,ProductQuantity) VALUES  (@ProductName,@ProductPrice,@ProductQuantity)        
    RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

And then from your C# code, have an output parameter with the return value of the SP:

```cs
var returnValue = new SqlParameter("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int)
    {
       Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    };

var ProductParameters = new[]{
   new SqlParameter("@ProductName",Product.ProductName),
   new SqlParameter ("@ProductPrice",Product.ProductPrice),
   new SqlParameter ("@ProductQuantity",Product.ProductQuantity),
   returnValue
};

db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC @ReturnValue = sp_InsertProduct @ProductName,@ProductPrice,@ProductQuantity", ProductParameters);

var scopeIdentity = (int)returnValue.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the `@id` variable.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertProduct]


    @ProductName varchar(30),
    @ProductPrice decimal ,
    @ProductQuantity int,

AS

BEGIN


INSERT INTO Product (ProductName,ProductPrice,ProductQuantity) VALUES  (@ProductName,@ProductPrice,@ProductQuantity)



RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY();

END
```

Comment: Thank you for your help , but how can i get the SCOPE_IDENTITY() in C# code?

Comment: I don't know if I would EXEC (by SQL query) the stored procedure like you're already doing. In any case the below answer would work as well. But just to answer your question, I would do something like: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37hwc7kt(v=vs.100).aspx ... create the cmd object and separate the parameters like so: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80x06z3b(v=vs.100).aspx